# Show popup with form before loading first view and pass data between controllers

Tags: ios, view, popup

What is the best way to show some kind of form or popup before the first view is shown on iOS? I need the user to fill in a few numbers which would affect the way the view looks.

I also need the filled in data regularly to perform calculations after the view is loaded. So if I were to chose a view for this task (and than switch to the next one, as suggested) how do I pass the data from the first to the next view/controller?

Answer (score 0):

Try looking in `AppDelegate.m`. There you will find a bunch of method which may interest you. `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` is the method that presents the first view.

Or try presenting a "temporary" view in which the user has to fill that form. From there you present your main view.

Answer (score 0):

The form you need would have to be the first view you load and display, after you get the info you need, you can hide the form, then load and display your main view (it's just not the first one anymore).

Comment: And how do I send that data from the first view/controller to the next one?

Comment: You can store the info in the App Delegate, or pass the data to the new view after you create it using properties on the new view controller.